# suggestion: We should collaborate with Deep Web Stackexchange community

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Good time of day! I think we should collaborate with Deep Web community - it's just started a public run and we defenately will have a frequent question routing between the communities. So my suggestion is - can we promote them in a right corner or something like that, so the questions about a Deep Web will go there and we will not have them as off-topic here? It's a mutual benefit, I presume!

Comment: Deep Web is actually in private beta at the moment...

Comment: @Quill so we need more users to spin it up, and I'm sure that these users are visiting Tor community for sure

Comment: If any user wants to participate in the private beta, you go to this link: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87978/deep-web then click visit under the blue number. Then log in with your normal account and you're in.

Comment: Deep web is fundamentally different than Dark Web.  Deep Web includes contents of databases that Google can't search by word, like on Arxiv and others.